# Do I need a Turkey transit visa for a layover?

Tags: visas, transit, layovers, indian-citizens, turkey

I have an Indian passport and am planning to visit Germany with a valid visa.
To book a flight for Germany (Mumbai – Dusseldorf), I came across some connected flights that stop at Istanbul.

Do I need to have visa for Turkey?  This is the first time I am travelling outside my country, and any information on this will be helpful.

Comment: How long is the layover? And is it with the same airline?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee, It is same airline(Turkish airline) and difference of time between flights is 1 hours 20 minute.

Comment: And definitely the same airport?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you don't need a transit visa - as long as you don't leave the transit lounge. But be sure about your change with airlines/planes, as there are two airports in Istanbul. You may read detailed information on the [Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa).

*Edit (not by Mahmut) to include extract from part of the referenced website:*

> **Question:** I will be flying to Europe. I know that our aircraft will land in İstanbul. I am not planning to leave the transit lounge. Do I need to get transit visa?
>
> **Answer:** If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you are not required to have transit visa.

*The above to attempt to clarify that in the above circumstances the nationality of the traveller appears irrelevant (though so does* "I will be flying to Europe"*, and interlining of luggage is not covered by the extract).*

Answer (score 8):

If you do not leave the airport transit area, then you do not need a transit visa.

From the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa):

> If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you are not required to have transit visa.

From [Turkish Airlines](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/baggage/transit-transfer-passenger-procedures):

> Passengers disembark with only their cabin baggage and proceed directly to the boarding gates without any flight or passport procedures.

From [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=TR&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C):

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.