# Do l need a transit visa for Turkey?

Tags: visas, transit, isl, cuban-citizens

I am a Cuban citizen flying from Cuba to Africa. I am changing planes in Istanbul Airport, with a layover of about 10 hours before going to Zimbabwe in Africa. My issue is that I am using 2 non aligned airlines, Aeroflot from Cuba to Istabnul and Egypt Air from Istanbul to Zimbabwe, Africa. I do not want to leave the airport. Do I need a transit visa, since I have to collect my bags and check in again for the other airline?

Comment: related:http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/do-i-need-a-turkey-transit-visa I think this might be a duplicate, as this map (http://www.ataturkairport.com/tr-TR/ucus_oncesi/Documents/gelis.pdf) may show you can use the transit desk to get the boarding documents (hard to verify). As for luggage, the airport does not detail your case: http://www.ataturkairport.com/en-EN/preflight/Pages/Transfer.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Whether or not you need a transit visa depends on 2 factors:

1. Which country your passport belongs to
2. If you need to leave the airport transit lounge

[Information for Cuban citizens going to Turkey is provided here.](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)

[I live in Ottawa (Canada) and as per the Turkish Embassy in Ottawa:](http://ottava.be.mfa.gov.tr/ConsularServices.aspx?ID=6)

> Transit visa is valid for up to three months and allows the person to
>   travel to another country through transiting the Turkish territory. If
>   the connecting flight to the third country does not require an
>   overnight stay in Turkey, then no visa is necessary. In other words,
>   Turkey does not issue Airport Transit Visa (ATV).

[From the Timaticweb application, here is the information specific to your situation.](http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&&NA=CU&AR=00&EM=CU&DE=ZW&TR=TR&VT=CU&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=MS&subuser=MS)

It says that if you hold a confirmed onward ticket, you don't need a visa.

**Personal experience:** I travelled from Toronto to Dubai via Instanbul as an Indian citizen and didn't need a transit visa but my situation differs because both my flights were on the same Turkish Airlines ticket.

**Recommendation:** Contact the Turkish Embassy in Cuba and verify with them. The fact that your onward flight is on a separate ticket may complicate the situation.

And finally, since you have a 10 hour wait, do consider...

**[EDIT: I just realized that this is only for Turkish Airlines passengers and you aren't a THY passenger. However, I'm leaving it on here since it might be of use to others.]**

[image]