# Visa for Istanbul trip during layover

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, istanbul

I am an Indian (Indian Passport) presently in Kano, Nigeria on a business visa. I am going back to Mumbai on 22 Sept by Turkish Airlines with a 12 hour layover time in Istanbul.  We plan to see the city during this time.

Can I get a visa on arrival?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need a Turkey transit visa for a layover?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/do-i-need-a-turkey-transit-visa-for-a-layover)

Comment: don't think this is a duplicate as the OP wants to get out of the airport, whereas the other person stayed in the transit area.

Comment: @drat I think the OP is just stating that they have a 12-hour connection at the airport, not that they need to go to Istanbul city.

Comment: @jpatokal I interpreted the 'We plan to see the city during this time.' as, they want to get out of the airport and see Istanbul.

Comment: @drat Whoops, totally missed that last phrase!  But I still think this is a dupe, the other answer makes it clear that they do need a visa in that case.

Comment: Seriously people.  The fact that a few words in the question are the same does not make it a duplicate.  The accepted answer for the other question in no way answers this persons question.

Answer (score 5):

Turkey no longer issues Visa-On-Arrival, so to answer your specific question, no, you can't get one.

The Visa-on-Arrival has been replaced by [e-Visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/), where you can apply for a visa in advance via their website, and it is normally issued immediately.

However as an Indian citizen you are only eligible for an e-Visa if you have a valid Schengen or OECD member countries visa in your passport. Presuming you do not, then you will need to apply for a standard visa via a Turkish consulate.