# Is a transit visa required in Istanbul?

Tags: turkey, transit-visas, isl, nigerian-citizens

My family and I are traveling to Dubai via Istanbul from Abuja, Nigeria. The layover is 12 hours. We have 2 little children, 1 infant and a senior in our party, all on Nigerian passports. I want to know if we require a transit visa and whether the facilities in the transit area good enough to stay there 12 hours if we decide to. We are flying Turkish Airlines.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. For any questions involving visas or entry, it is good to indicate what nationality passport(s) your party be traveling on. According to *[Do I need a Turkey transit visa for a layover?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14054)*, no transit visa is required if you remain in the transit area, but I cannot speak to its suitability for spending half a day. Are you looking for any specific amenities or facilities?

Comment: We all carry Nigerian passports

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a transit visa as long as you stay in the international area, according to Turkey's e-visa [portal](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/)

> **Do I have to obtain a visa if I do not leave the international transit
>   area?**
>   No. You do not have to get a visa if you are not going to
>   leave the international transit area.

More of the same from the Turkish Ministry of Foreign [Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa)

> **Question**: I will be flying to Europe. I know that our aircraft will
>   land in İstanbul. I am not planning to leave the transit lounge. Do I
>   need to get transit visa?
>
> **Answer**: If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you
>   are not required to have transit visa. Otherwise, you have to make
>   visa application to the nearest Turkish Representation. Contact
>   information of the said missions can be reached through www.mfa.gov.tr
>   (Ministry/Turkish Representations).