# Transit visa for Philippine passport holder

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, turkey, filipino-citizens, kuwait

I was granted an EEA Family Permit to join my husband in the UK. Do I need a transit visa for a 6-hour stopover, either in Kuwait or Turkey? I would be staying airside only.

Answer (score 3):

For Kuwait no visa is required for:

> Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

according to [SkyTeam](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/).

For Turkey either change settings at SkyTeam above or "no" - see [Do I need a Turkey transit visa for a layover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/do-i-need-a-turkey-transit-visa-for-a-layover)