# Do I need a transit visa in Istanbul airport if the transfer time is under 4 hours?

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, istanbul, vietnamese-citizens

I am from Vietnam and intending to fly to Manchester (UK) with Turkish Airways with a layover under 4 hours at the Istanbul Airport (Turkey). Will I require a transit visa for the layover in Istanbul airport if the transfer time is under 4 hours at the airport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a Turkey transit visa for a layover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/do-i-need-a-turkey-transit-visa-for-a-layover)

Comment: A visa is not required if will remain airside However If It was me i would spend $45 more on the trip and get an instant e-Visa for turkey online and select a flight with a little longer layover and take a free Istanbul tour with Turkish Airlines. That is so well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as you don't leave the air-side area you don't need a visa. I spent a good 12 hours stuck air-side at Ataturk airport back in 2012 transiting on a flight back from Tokyo to London.

It's also worth noting that quite a few countries can get visa on arrival/E - visa for Turkey if you would like to leave the air-side area