# Do I need to clear immigration for a layover in IST?

Tags: layovers, canadian-citizens, istanbul

I'm looking at a flight to Europe with Turkish Airlines and a short layover (1.5 hours) in Istanbul (same ticket). Do transiting passengers need to clear Turkish immigration before proceeding? I'm trying to determine if the layover is too short for me and having to clear passport control would further shorten it.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/do-i-need-a-turkey-transit-visa-for-a-layover

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no you don't have to go through immigration.

Considering that you will be travelling on a **single ticket** and your transit duration is **less than 24 hours** the following would apply

> International transfer passengers flight routes issued on single
>   ticket continuing to a foreign destination with Turkish Airlines*
>
> - Passengers disembark with only their cabin baggage and proceed directly to the boarding gates without any flight or passport procedures.
> - Passengers who have not obtained their boarding pass for the connecting flight at the initial point of departure must apply to the 
>     Turkish Airlines Transit Check-in desk.
>
> *Including which flight routes issued on single ticket, Star Alliance members and airlines with a codeshare agreement with Turkish Airlines.

source: http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/baggage/transit-transfer-passenger-procedures

Comment: I had a flypgs ticket for SAW and Atlas ticket for out, 3 hours stay, seperate tickets seperately paid, no issues, check in staff at first airport asked me onward ticket amd visa for my real destination; n no issues at SAW too. Online checkin. Only cabin luggage