# Does a Filipino flying from Vietnam to Brazil need a visa or transit visa to layover in Istanbul or Doha Qatar?

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, filipino-citizens, istanbul, doh

Planning to travel from Vietnam to Brazil via Turkish Airlines with a layover in Istanbul, or via Qatar Airways with a layover is in Doha Qatar.

Is it possible to layover in Istanbul or Doha without visa/transit visa?

If I checked my luggage with either possible airlines, do I need to pick up the luggage in the layover country and check it in again? Or it automatically follows through my final destination which is in Brazil?

Comment: I have edited the title and body for clarity. If I have misstated anything, the changes can be reverted to your original wording. I do not understand your last sentece — "Or it automatically follows through my final destination which is in Brazil?" What does this mean?

Comment: @David I presume they're asking if their Brazilian visa will allow them to transit through Istanbul or Doha.  (There are countries/airports with arrangements like this: for example, you generally don't need a Schengen transit visa if you're going to the US and have a US visa.)

Comment: I mean, the luggage. Do I need to pick it up in the layover country and check it in again or it will automatically check through my final destination?

Answer (score 8):

**No**, you do not need a transit visa for either country.  This assumes you have connecting flights on a single ticket from the same airport (Istanbul has three) and you don't need to recheck bags etc.

Per Qatar Airways, [anybody can transit through Doha, Qatar without a visa](https://qatarairways.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206466228-Do-I-need-a-visa-for-transiting-in-Doha-) as long as they don't leave the airport.

Turkey's transit visa policy is covered here: [Do I need a Turkey transit visa for a layover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/do-i-need-a-turkey-transit-visa-for-a-layover)