# Does a US Citizen need a visa to leave the Istanbul airport?

Tags: transit-visas, us-citizens, turkey, turkish-airlines, ist

I am traveling from the United States and my layover in Istanbul is 24hrs (Turkish Airlines). Do I need a visa to leave the airport? If so how much is it?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you need a visa to leave the airport.

According to [Do I need a Turkey transit visa for a layover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14054/18374) you don't need a visa when the transit is just 24 hours, but that is if you stay at the airport the whole time.

If you want to leave then you have to get a visa.

The Electronic Visa (e-Visa) Application System was launched on 17 April 2013 by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Republic of Turkey. This system allows visitors travelling to Turkey to easily obtain their [e-Visas online](https://www.evisa.gov.tr), in approximately three minutes. The e-Visa cost **20 USD**.